# Averaging production percentages (Hourly) based on different values for a total for the day?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add a daily average of the hours used vs the items completed. The problem is, some items are done by how many there are to do (e.g. 5 EA) and some are based on feet to install (e.g. 100 FT). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zKn.jpg) is the link to an image that should help to clarify what my post doesn't say well.

I'm not sure how to best accomplish the above with a formula I can use within "Conditional Formatting" to highlight the cells in green, yellow, or red based on the day's totals.
Below is the formula that I have attempted to use to achieve my goal but I have a feelings that it is wrong as the results don't seem to add up to me (in F:41, I feel that that should at least be yellow and not red). I'm sure that I am missing something simple, but I just don't know what it could be.

```
=F41/(SUMPRODUCT($G$18:$G$38,$X$18:$X$38)/($X$18:$X$38))>0.95
=F41/(SUMPRODUCT($G$18:$G$38,$X$18:$X$38)/($X$18:$X$38))>=0.9
=F41/(SUMPRODUCT($G$18:$G$38,$X$18:$X$38)/($X$18:$X$38))<0.9
```

As my formula above says, I'm trying to color based on the value being greater than or less than a certain percentage. The colors are explained in the image attached.

I'm honestly at a loss as to the best way to handle this, and it may be that I am over thinking it honestly. I've been known to do that on more than one occasion.

**Note**: The hours are not all worked in one day, but I was testing a variety of cells to make sure my formula carried correctly. Hours are based on (2) people working an 8 hour day for a total of 16 hours per day (hence the odd look there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula below is what ended up working. It took a bit of time, but I did get it working.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(G18:G38,1/X18:X38)/F41>0.95
=SUMPRODUCT(G18:G38,1/X18:X38)/F41>=0.9
=SUMPRODUCT(G18:G38,1/X18:X38)/F41<0.9
```